# single HTML file for navigation bar in every file

Tags: html, navigation

I have more than 20 pages in my website.If I want to change any line, I need to do the changes in every files.If you have any solution for this ,Please let me know.Help me....

Comment: You will need to use a templating engine.

Comment: how to use a templating engine.

Comment: Look into something like Handlebars/Moustache templates, Jekyll, Metalsmith.